# Android ui distorts on setting large size text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The UI of my app distorts when I'm setting large text. The height of the button "confirm sale" gets distort in devices with small screen(I'm testing with screen size of 4.5inch).It looks perfectly fine in tabs. I want all these button of same height.

My layout code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/light_grey" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_total_draft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"

           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save_draft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="New"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_goto_draft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Open"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="Confirm\nsale"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your result image in somewhere then include it to your question. Post the whole xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Try by giving the `Button` height as `match_parent` instead of 'wrap_content'.

Replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.
Then output will be like below

[image: Now your layout will be look like this]

And `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` this property will be invalid for child of `LinearLayout`